# Marionette CompositeView attachHtml after rather than append

Tags: jquery, sails.js, marionette, waterline, insertafter

I have a model with and parent child relationship which I'd like to display in table display each parent followed by it children, where I'll indent the children slightly. I'm nearly there but I can only seem to append the children to the parent row rather than adding them after the parent row.

```
View.TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: listItemTpl,
  tagName: "tr",
  initialize: function() {
    var children = new Backbone.Collection(this.model.get('children'));
    if (this.model.get('parent')) {
      this.$el.addClass('child');
    } else {
      this.$el.addClass('parent');
    }
    this.collection = children;
  },

  attachHtml: function(collectionView, childView, index) {
    collectionView.$el.append(childView.el);
  }
});

View.TreeRoot = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  tagName: "table",
  className: "table table-bordered table-striped",
  childView: View.TreeView,
  template: listTpl,
  childViewContainer: "tbody"
});
```

I've tried

```
collectionView.$el.after(childView.el);
```

but that doesn't work at all.

My model parent child is created server side using sailsjs like below.

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    category: {
      model: 'Category'
    },
    parent: {
      model: 'Term'
    },
    children: {
      collection: 'Term',
      via: 'parent'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Parent and children will be rows of the same table? Is that it?

Comment: Could you show the collection/model code as well?

Comment: Yes so want all the rows in the same table by they they will be arrange like

Parent
Child
Child
Child
Parent
Child
Child
Child
Parent
Child
Child
Child

Not sure my backbone model and collection will be of much use as it doesn't do that much.

Comment: Well, the model tell us how your relation between Parent and Children have been done. I does matter while choosing the best approach.

Comment: OK it's probably better to show the model from the server using sails js as this is what generates the json with the parent child relationship.
`module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    category: {
      model: 'Category'
    },
    parent: {
      model: 'Term'
    },
    children: {
      collection: 'Term',
      via: 'parent'
    }
  }
};`

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar problem and i ended up using multiple tables instead.. Putting the parent object in thead and the children in tbody.

So a tip if you wanna go this way:

Use a compositeView with it's model being the parent object, the collection the children and it's template being your table.
Display your model data inside the thead section, make the childViewContainer the tbody and use tr as tagName.

(Thanks to JSteunou @ GitHub)

```
List.Child = App.Views.ItemView.extend({
  template: "urltotemplate",
  tagName: 'tr'
});

List.Parent = App.Views.CompositeView.extend({
  template: "urltotemplate",
  tagName: 'table',
  childView: List.Child,
  childViewContainer: 'tbody',

  initialize: function(options){
    this.collection = this.model.get("children");
  }
});

List.Parents = App.Views.CompositeView.extend({
  template: "urltotemplate",
  childView: List.Parent,
  childViewContainer: 'div.container'

});
```